What is the timescale for "$ Change" and "% Change" on Vanguard's Holdings page?
When I navigate to my account on Vanguard, the page shows my various holdings, along with "$ Change" and "% Change". But what timescale is used to calculate these values? Are they calculated as change over the last day (or week, or month, or year)? It's quite surprising the Vanguard website nowhere explains the meaning of these values.


These are daily changes. For longer timescales you need to go to the performance tab.

Thanks! How do you know this? Is it documented anywhere, or is this just a universal standard among online portfolio trackers?

I couldn't find it anywhere on the page, but it is a universal standard across brokerages to show daily change for positions.
